# how to use a controller in a custom nova component with laravel and vue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

**thanks in advance.**
I'm pritty new in laravel nova.
I've created a new controller for my custom component and cant get the routing to work, I keep getting a 404. The api route is in the custom nova-component directory: here some examples how i'm trying to reach the controller.
My map structure: [my map structure of my custom nova component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1gR.png)

```
Route::post('/create-new-content', '\nova-components\{mycustomcova component}\Http\Controllers\Controller@CreateNewItem');
Route::post('/create-new-content', 'Controller@CreateNewItem');
```

I've played around with the mapping and still recieved, does not exists in my putty where i'm looking for my routes with the route:list command.
I've searched and cound't find anything related to my problem.

**edit:**
I found a workaround. not sure if it's best practice, any input about the best pratice are welkom!
The way i wanted it to do was creating a function in the controller but i coudn't reach it. so instead of calling the functionin my api.php, i put the function in the ap.php like so: `axios.get('/nova-vendor/{MyCustomComponent}/function').then(response => { this.$toasted.show('Data is loaded!', { type: 'success' }); console.log(response.data);});`
All tips and tricks are welkom!